# group-mean centering and log differenced variables

Tags: regression, logarithm

I have a country-mean centered explanatory variable (X- country mean) in panel data. The variable itself and the mean are transformed with the natural log. The outcome variable is also made like this. How do I interpret such coefficients in linear regression?

Is it like 1% increase in X gives % change in the outcome?